# How to get TWO Previous record in MySQL using CURSOR

Tags: sql, sql-server

On my table, I have record**s** that contain ','.

```
Id           Name
1            Here is the result
2            of your examination.
3            ,  
4            New Opening for the position of 
5            PT Teacher, Science Lab.
6            ,
```

So in cursor If I found ',' then I want to merge the 2 rows value into the first one.

```
DECLARE @ID int
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(500)

DECLARE MergeCursor CURSOR FOR 
select ID,NAME from  TEST_TABLE 

OPEN MergeCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM NarrationCursor into @ID,@NAME

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
BEGIN 
    
    if(@Name = ',')
        select * from TEST_TABLE where ID = (select max(ID) from TEST_TABLE where ID < @ID)
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM NarrationCursor into @ID,@NAME
END

CLOSE MergeCursor
DEALLOCATE MergeCursor
```

**IN cursor how can I get the PREVIOUS TWO-ROW And UPDATE the value in 1st row and DELETE THE 2nd and THIRD ROW. AS WELL AS UPDATE THE ID**

In the End, I want to output

```
Id           Name
1            Here is the result of your examination.
2            New Opening for the position of PT Teacher, Science Lab.
```

Comment: MySQL (owned by Oracle) is not the same thing as SQL Server (owned by Microsoft). You're using the latter, please correct your tags. Regardless, WHY do you NEED to do this in a cursor? It can be done much more simply and efficiently with window functions in a normal query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH
  grouped AS
(
  SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN name=',' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      OVER (ORDER BY id)
        AS group_id,
    id,
    name
  FROM
    TEST_TABLE
)
SELECT
  group_id + 1   AS id,
  STRING_AGG(name, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id)   AS name
FROM
  grouped
WHERE
  name <> ','
GROUP BY
  group_id
ORDER BY
  group_id
```

Comment: I got all the records in one row using your query.
`1            Here is the result of your examination., New Opening for the position of PT Teacher, Science Lab.`

Comment: @VeetThomson Then your "comma rows" aren't actually `','` as it works fine here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ca5ba958630caa2760e4ee70868fd81a You probably have some whitespace / control-code characters in there. Either fix the data, or change the code to match the marker actually in use.

Comment: yes it is working now. I don't know how? Thank you very much.